# How can I apply AVERAGEIFS on all cells of a column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, how do I automatically apply `AVERAGEIFS` on each cell of a column?

For illustration purposes, say I have a sheet with temperature recordings and a corresponding date.

| Temperature | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-11-01 |
| 6 | 2023-11-01 |
| 5 | 2023-11-01 |
| 8 | 2023-11-02 |
| 4 | 2023-11-03 |
| 2 | 2023-11-03 |
| 0 | 2023-11-05 |

I want to automatically fill a separate column which would automatically calculate the average temperature for each unique date.

| Unique Date | Avg temperature |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-11-01 | ? |
| 2023-11-02 | ? |
| 2023-11-03 | ? |
| 2023-11-05 | ? |

**Context:**

With certain functions like `UNIQUE` or `ARRAYFORMULA`, it is possible to automatically fill all cells of a column with a function specified in the top row. For instance:

[image: Automatically filling all the cells using the UNIQUE function]

How do I do that using `AVERAGEIFS`?

Getting the list of unique dates automatically is trivial using the UNIQUE function: `=UNIQUE(temperature!$B2:B)`

Getting the conditional average cell-by-cell is also very easy: `=AVERAGEIFS(temperature!$A2:$A, temperature!$B2:$B, A2)`

I need however to enter this formula once and let Google Sheets generate all the temperature averages by date automatically, even as I add new temperature rows. Manually expending the formula by dragging the cell will not do.

Using `ARRAYFORMULA` by itself only returns one cell and does not automatically fill the bottom cells, so I can use a workaround and use IF: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($A2:$A<>"", AVERAGEIFS(temperature!$A2:$A, temperature!$B2:$B, A2), ""))`

But this will filter all the temperatures based on the first unique date only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with QUERY and AVG inside it:

```
=QUERY(A:B,"SELECT B,AVG(A) WHERE B is not null GROUP BY B",1)
```

[image]